# BigQuery: DDL statement not executing via client API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am executing `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST` via client API using following `JobConfigurationQuery`:

```
queryConfig.setUseLegacySql(false)
queryConfig.setFlattenResults(false)
queryConfig.setQuery(query)
```

As I am executing CREATE TABLE DDL, I cannot specify destination table, write dispositions, etc. In my Query History section of Web UI, I see job being executed **successfully** without any exceptions, and with no writes happening. Is DDL statement not supported via client API?

I am using following client:  `"com.google.apis" % "google-api-services-bigquery" % "v2-rev397-1.23.0"`

Answer (score 2):

From [BigQuery docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#creating_a_table_only_if_the_table_doesnt_exist) which says it seems that no error is returned when table exists:

> The CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DDL statement creates a table with the
>   specified options only if the table name does not exist in the
>   dataset. **If the table name exists in the dataset, no error is
>   returned**, and no action is taken.

Answering your question, DDL is supported from API which is also stated in doc, to do this:

> Call the jobs.query method and supply the DDL statement in the request
>   body's query property.